# Convert Output Size of Fourier Transformed Signal Using Pytorch (torch.rfft)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, fft, dft

I’m trying to run a image fourier transformation with various output sizes of signal using pytorch. For example,suppose that the input size of image is [3x32x32] and the output size of fourier transformation is [3x64x64], then ideal code can be represented as **torch.rfft(input, signal_ndim=3, n=(3,64,64))** (if given n is the output size of signal).

However, pytorch doesn’t seem to offer the argument ‘n’. According to the pytorch fft documentation, N represents the output size of signal, but cannot be modified in the code.

**SO, does anyone know how to change the output size of fourier transformed signal using pytorch?** I would appreciate if anyone can tell me a solution to change the output size of fourier trasformed signal.

You can see that numpy-fft library uses the argument ‘s’ as the output size of the signal in the code.

1. **Numpy**
   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftn.html
   numpy.fft.fftn(a, s=None, axes=None, norm=None)

   -> ‘s’ denotes shape of the output of signal.
   **Simple code**

   ```
   import torch
   import numpy as np

   np_a = torch.rand(3, 32, 32).numpy()
   np_a_ft = np.fft.fftn(a, (3,28, 28))
   print(np_a_ft.shape)
   ```

   ```
   Input size of image                    : 3, 32, 32  
   Output size of after fourier transform : 3, 28, 28
   ```
2. **Pytorch**
   https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rfft.html
   torch.rfft(input, signal_ndim, normalized=False, onesided=True)

   ```
   torch_x   = torch.rand(3, 32, 32, requires_grad=True)
   torch_xf  = torch.rfft(torch_x, 3)
   print(torch_xf.size())
   ```

   ```
   torch.Size([3, 32, 17, 2])
   ```

Comment: What that argument does in other libraries is pad the input with zeros: just add zeros to make the matrix the right shape, then apply the FFT.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That would be work!